# How to monitor an offline linux and export the data from time to time

Tags: monitoring

I have an offline system (a robot running Ubuntu, not connected to any network) I want to monitor the resource usage over time (mainly CPU and memory). I am used to Influx and Prometheus and i was wondering if there was a tool to save the monitoring data and store until I connect to the machine and export the data, and if possible export it to an online prometheus or influx instance.

I've looked at [Promequeen](https://github.com/Cleafy/promqueen), but it seems outdated and creates a new prometheus database instead of appending the data to one.

Are there some tools or an industry standard for this scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by offline, turned off or disconnected from regular Network ? if turned off, you can probably use Wake on LAN, disconnected should use a gateway from SCADA Network to Regular and it can work as usual by forwarding the correct port.

Comment: By offline I mean running but not connected to the internet (or any LAN whatsoever).

Comment: No way for disconnected machines and that's why i'm using the so-called SCADA Networks which are isolated except certain flows through NAT & GW.

Comment: The robot is a wireless mobile robot and is transported from a working site to another every day, thus cannot have dangling cable and cannot rely on on-site equipment. Network, SCADA or not, is not an option for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've given up using Prometheus, which without a tool like Promqueen isn't made to receive out-of-date data.

I set up Telegraf on the robot and made it output the data in Influx line protocol, so I just have to retrieve the metrics file and import it into a Influx database.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Prometheus Pushgateway, it store metrics until deleted and push metrics directly to Prometheus on demand.

Comment: There would be two issues if I understand correctly how it works:
1. If I scrape every two day, I would have a data point only every two day, and I'll lose the data in between.
2. I would need a push-compatible exporter. For instance, I'm used to cadvisor to monitor container CPU and memory usage, but it doesn't support pushing.

Comment: ad 1. What do you mean by "I'll lose the data in between"? Push gateway store all the data unless deleted.
Ad 2. Yes, you would.

Comment: I would have the last data pushed to the gateway. For example, if I push the cpu_time for each process during two days and then scrape the data, prometheus would only show the last data point. That would be the total cpu_time for every process ran within those two days, but I would not have access to the variations between the start and the end of each process.

Comment: I see. I haven't realized that the metrics in PG doesn't accumulate as set of values. Sorry for that.